# Count distinct occurrences and add them

Tags: mysql

I have the following table,
|      Name      |     Choice    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          John         |         1       |
|          John         |         1       |
|          John         |         3       |
|          Alex         |         3       |
|          John         |         4       |
|          Liam         |         2       |

I want to find how many distinct choices everyone has. So the output after the query should be,
|      Name      |     numberOfChoices    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          John         |         3       |
|          Alex         |         1       |
|          Liam         |         1       |

I've been trying to use `GROUP BY` and `INNNER JOIN` but cant seem to make this work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` name and count `DISTINCT` choices

```
SELECT `Name`, COUNT(DISTINCT `Choice`)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY `Name`
```